# WPF binding to label doesn't working?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

There is a grid view that listing something from a class property.  Class havinf four property, outof which three I m binding to 3 columns of grid view and last property I binded to another label.

The grid view is working and binding the values but Lable is not... What is the reason?

```
public class ProjectData
{
     public string ProjectName {get;set;}
        public string MachineName {get;set;}
        public string MachineNumber {get;set;}
        public string StatusDetail {get;set;}
}
```

Here is xaml:

```
 <ListView 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
            Name="PrjtListView" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
            FontSize="15" Background="#FFF2F2B7" 
            BorderThickness="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectData}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" 
                      ColumnHeaderToolTip="appconfig servers"
                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
                     <GridViewColumn Header="Project Name" Width="400"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProjectName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Build Machine" Width="150"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MachineName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Port number" Width="120" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MachineNumber}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <UniformGrid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="add to cctray" Margin="0,0,5,0" 
                    Command="{Binding AddToCCTray}"/>
        </UniformGrid>
        **<Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Name="lblTotalProjects" FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic"
Content="{Binding StatusDetail}"></Label>**  
                 -->> This is not working
```

This is just code snippet,I will give other details if required.

**EDIT: Can we bind the same datacontext twice in same xaml file. One for some other controls and one for some other controls**

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you set the value of the `StatusDetail`-property later than the controls are created.
Because [auto-properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) do not support any change notification, the label will not know that there is some data and therefore does not show any content.
Try implementing [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) for your properties. This will probably fix your problem.

Comment: That everything I implemented... the other three properties works charm but the last property is not getting bound. I implemented OnPropertyChanged

Comment: @GAPS: Check the output window of visual studio. If there is binding error, you will see that in this window. I have seen that you have given the label a name. Check if you don't set a value for the Content property from your code behind. This would remove the binding.

Comment: @GAPS: Look at the solution of Jens (+1), propbably this is it, I have overlooked the fact that the other properties are used for building the items.

Answer (score 1):

It may be the reason that you define  ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectData}" within ListView scope and your Label doesen't know its Binding source. Set "DataContext" of your View to "ProjectData" instance this might help.

Comment: No... DataContext to ListView doesn't work. Even that doesn't populate gridview also.

Comment: @GAPS you can leave ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectData}" from your ListView and add the View's DataContext to ProjectData so that make  label binding working.

Answer (score 1):

The label is outside of the ListView, and therefore has a different DataContext than the rows of your grid.

I am guessing that your current DataContext has a `IList<ProjectData>` called ProjectData, otherwise the ItemsSource binding would fail. If that's true, for which item should StatusDetail be displayed? If this label should appear in every grid row, once for each item, you'd need to create a new column for that.

Also, have a look at your output window. Binding error give good error messages there.

Comment: Ya you are correct. If I add the StatusDetail in ListView, its working. So again assigning the DataContext as ProjectData to label should work. but `<Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Name="lblTotalProjects" DataContext="{Binding ProjectData}" Content="{Binding StatusDetail}"></Label>` is also not working.

Comment: @GAPS: No, it should not work. A ListView takes an IList (or IEnumerable?) of Items, generates a row for each one and sets the DataContext of this row to the Item. So setting the DataContext of the Label to the ItemsSource of the ListView should never have the desired effect.

Comment: Then how to do that... same xaml file can have two or more than two data context?

Comment: @GAPS: Does binding the label's content to `{Binding SelectedItem.StatusDetail, ElementName=PrjtListView}` work for your case?

Comment: @Jens That's working but only when I click or select the items in gridview. I want when ever any update occur on grid view, even in case of binding also, the label should changes

Comment: @GAPS: So.. you've got a list of ProjectData items in your Grid, and the label underneath it. The StatusDetail of which Item should be shown?

Answer (score 0):

I always set my binding to `{Binding Path="StatusDetail"}`

Hope that helps a bit for you.

Comment: `{Binding Path="StatusDetail"}` `{Binding StatusDetail}` Both are same